# CruiseControl.Net messages for "Last Build Status"

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, message

Could anyone help me with reporting?

I want to make my dashboard more informative, so if it possible to put custom message for the last build status? Now, in case of failure I have just a message "Failing Tasks: Executable Task" (see picture below). How can I write there which particular task failed? Can the task write something from itself?
[image]

Please, point me to the right direction of looking for.
Thanks for a help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting CruiseControl.NET to use output from long-running task when displaying "Activity"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304890/getting-cruisecontrol-net-to-use-output-from-long-running-task-when-displaying)

Comment: I found out how to do it. The all I need - just to add description attribute to <exec> nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it. The all I need - just to add description attribute to  nodes.