# CCNET: Can I get more meaningful logging than <task name="echo">?

Tags: logging, cruisecontrol.net, nant

**Meaningful task names** If I `View the Build Log` for my CCNET project, I can see messages like

```
<task name="echo">
  <message level="Info"><![CDATA[Done: clean]]></message>
  <duration>0</duration>
</task>
```

or

```
<task name="property">
  <duration>15.6247</duration>
</task>
```

In some cases I see these are the `NANT` tasks configured for my `target`. Is there a way to configure either my NANT file or my CC config so I get a more meaningful, more easily identifiable log message from these tasks?

I'm using Version : 1.5.6804.1.

---

Nice to have:

**Timestamps**
It would be also nice to get timestamps on these, or better, timestams on *everything*.

**Build Log transformation** Is there an easy (eg. built-in, not-from-scratch) way to get a transformed/nicer view of the build log on the web Dashboard? (I guess I could write an XSL but it's strange to me that I get a pure xml view, am I missing something?)

**Output absorption** I also have the feeling that some lines I echo from tasks or 3rd party executables, gets parsed and somehow stripped by CC before it is written to the log. Is there a part of CC that is tipically doing things like this?

**Best practices** Alternatively, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you produce a small example where nant output is lost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting CruiseControl.NET to use output from long-running task when displaying "Activity"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304890/getting-cruisecontrol-net-to-use-output-from-long-running-task-when-displaying)

Answer (score 1):

**Customizing Build Protocol Format**
Normally you do not stare directly at the build protocol, only when debugging the xsl transforms converting it into more human-friendly html. That said you could write your own nant logger, add `-logger:your.logger.class -logfile:mynantlog.xml` to nant build arguments and merge the `mynantlog.xml` file afterwards into the build log.

**Timing**
Would be nice to have but it is currently not possible. You would have to write your own logger or sprinkle `<tstamp verbose="true" />` everywhere.

**Build Log Transformation**
I would say writing XSL is easier than programming your own transformations in a scripting language. The dashboard already comes with a couple of useful transformations in the `xsl`subdirectory that you might look at and tweak, for example (dashboard.config)

```
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Output" actionName="BuildReportNAnt"  xslFileName="xsl\NAnt.xsl"/>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Timings" actionName="BuildReportNAntTimings" xslFileName="xsl\NAntTiming.xsl"/>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="Warning and Errors" actionName="BuildReportWE" xslFileName="xsl\compile.xsl"/>
```

**Output Absorpation**
No, CC does not filter your build protocol. If you are loosing your output when invoking another instance of NAnt (using `<exec>` or `<nant>`) try updating to a newer version, yours is quite old.

**Best Practices**
Dig into XML, XPath and XSL if you are sticking with CC.net and NAnt.

Comment: `output absorption`: I found an example. If I emit a line from a python script that *starts with* "[1]", it gets stripped, due (I guess) to the enclosing square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'built in' nant xsl 'plugin'.

Go to the administration for through dashboard and you should be able to turn it on.

As for the rest there are no built in plugins to do what you are looking for (timestamps, tidy-up of output)

I've not noticed Nant output disappearing, or not making it to the build log.